# Does MySQL use only one index per query/sub-query?

Tags: mysql, performance

Please assume the following query:

```
select dic.*, d.syllable
from dictionary dic 
join details d on d.word = dic.word
```

As you know (and I heard), MySQL uses only one index per query. Now I want to know, in query above, which index would be better?

- `dictionary(word)`
- `details(word)`

In another word, when there is a `join` (two tables are involved), the index of which one would be affected?  Should I create both of them (on the columns on the `on` clause) and MySQL itself decides using which one is better?

Comment: In your example, it seems like word would be the primary key for both tables.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  If `word` is the PK of both tables, why have two tables instead of combining them??

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to discuss things further.

Comment: MySQL will do a table scan of one table, then use an index to reach into the other.  Adding a `WHERE` would radically change the discussion!

Answer (score 4):

> As you know (and I heard), MySQL uses only one index per query.

In general, most databases will only use one index *per table*, per query.  This isn't always the case, but is at least a decent rule of thumb.  For your particular example, you can rely on this.

> Now I want to know, in query above, which index would be better?

The query you wrote is actually an inner join.  This means that either of the two tables could appear on the left side of the join, and the result sets would be logically equivalent.  As a result of this, MySQL is therefore free to write the join in any order it chooses.  The plan that gets chosen will likely place the larger table on the left hand side, and the smaller table on the right hand side.  If you knew the actual execution order of the tables, then you would just index the right table.  Given that you may not know this, then both of your suggested indices are reasonable:

```sql
CREATE INDEX dict_idx ON dictionary (word);
CREATE INDEX details_idx ON details (word);
```

We could even try to improve on the above indices by covering the columns which appear in the select clause.  For example, the index on `details` could be expanded to:

```sql
CREATE INDEX details_idx ON details (word, syllable);
```

This would let MySQL use the above index exclusively to satisfy the query plan, without requiring a seek back to the original table.  You select `dictionary.*`, so covering this with a single index might not be possible or desirable, but at least this gets the point across.

Comment: *In general, most databases will only use one index per table, per query.* Not per table but per table copy. If a table is used twice or more in a query, each copy may use its own index which, of course, may differ.

Comment: I think the Optimizer starts with the smaller table when nothing contradicts that.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL would use the most selective index (the one giving the fewest rows).  This means it depends on the data, and also optimizations like this could change between versions of the database.

Comment: *MySQL would use the most selective index* This is not true in general.

Comment: @Akina  "To eliminate rows from consideration. If there is a choice between multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the index that finds the smallest number of rows". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: The most general example is the case when less selective but covering index is present.

Comment: That is the answer to a different question (not being asked).

Comment: See Tim's answer - his suggestion to create covering index by `details` table is useful for the question. I doubt that the question is not practical, and that OP needs in theory only. Also pay attention to the words which you citate - "normally" but not "always" is used in it.

Comment: Op asked if index on dictionary(word) or on details(word) would be used.  Tim doesn't seem to answer the question but instead says to use a covering index.  This is very good information, of course.  Anyways, op decides what was most useful.